# How to give Public_html to each user?

Tags: server, apache2, users

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to have 2 or more users be able to test with apache/php/mysql.

Within default config at sites-available I added two different VirtualHosts, one for each user lets say : **/home/user1/public_html** and **/home/user2/public_html**

Now I can view the index.php from the user1 at localhost/index.php but I can't do the same for user2. 
I know there must be a way but I dont know how to google search for it.

Any ideas or maybe point me to the correct direction?

PS: guess the title isn't accurate but I could't think any better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, revert the changes you made at sites-available.

Enable userdir module: `sudo a2enmod userdir`, and restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Now you can access the files in `/home/<username>/public_html` through `http://1.2.3.4/~<username>/`.

For example:

- `http://your.host.name/~user1`
- `http://your.host.name/~user2`