# LAMP 404 Page Not Found

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, lamp

I'm trying to access at my project on `index.php` page which is using the framework Slim on my localhost. However, I get 404 PAGE NOT FOUND.

- I created a symbolic link to `/home/user/public_html` from `/var/www/html`
- I allowed all permissions with `chmod 777` on `public_html`
- My project is located on `/home/user/public_html`
- Here is my `.htaccess` file:

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
  ```
- I can access a php file which contains `phpinfo()`. It is located on `/public_html`
- `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

I'm not using VirtualHost. Could that be the problem?

[image: 404 Page Not Found error]

Comment: Is the root folder of your site setup well?

Comment: I think ... How can I know that ? ^^

Comment: Usually, this is done using a Virtual host file for the site! Don't use the named framework but I will look it up!

Comment: So I will try to use VirtualHost. I back if I solved the problem, or not ...

Comment: install slim now will run it from my end and revert back!

Comment: I done some test by creation folder and file and that's works. I think it's the project configuration that's wrong . Maybe .htaccess ... ?

Comment: Is apache's rewrite module enabled? Run the following command `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo apache2ctl restart` and try again.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm editing my post to mentioned that.

Comment: `Hello World slim framework!` using `localhost/askubuntu` in browser window

Comment: @NicolasLamblin This is my `.htaccess` file: `Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.htaccess` file to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

to allow symbolic links to work

In addition to the above settings, I see that you have an additional folder called `M1-CSI` in `public_html` link in `/var/www/htnl`. Now note that `apache` uses the `/var/www/html` as the root folder hence either your `index.php` is in `/var/www/html` of in a folder for your project located in `/var/www/html/project_folder`.

So set up the `slim` project in `/home/user/public_html` and the `public_html` as the `root` for `slim`. Your symbolic link should have been... `sudo ln -s /home/user/public_html /var/www/html/` with the folder `/public_html` as root. To usee `M1-CSI` you will need to use a `Virtualhost` file and ofcourse midify your `require vendor/autoload.php` line to `require ../vendor/autoload.php`.

Another note is the fact that your ownership is `root` now that isn't what you want I believe, the `www-data` user should be in charge of those files. Add yourself to that group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

Then change ownership of that file to:

```
sudo chown -R $USER.www-data /var/www/html/public_html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/public_html
```

Note: A reboot will be needed to get the new group set working.

How I setup my `slim` project using this [link](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/installation.html):

1. Created a folder in `/var/www/html` called `askubuntu`
2. `cd /var/www/html/askubuntu`
3. `composer require slim/slim "^3.0"`
4. Then created an `index.php` file in `askubuntu` folder with the following lines:

   ```
   <?php

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   echo "Hello World slim framework!";
   ?>
   ```
5. Open my browser and enter: `localhost/askubuntu`, and it prints the expected output.

Comment: I tried but doesn't change the problem ... Thank's for your time ! Have you follow a tutorial for Slim setup ?

Comment: Yes I have it running on my end and can access it from `localhost/askubuntu`

Comment: Please run `ls -l /var/www/html/public_html` and let me see the ownership!

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 nov.  13 11:55 /var/www/html/public_html -> /home/nicolas/public_html

Comment: Please use this add in the browser `localhost/public_html`, and I see `M1-CSI` what is that supposed to be? You `index.php` should be in `/var/www/html/public_html` not `M1-CSI`

Comment: Yes exactly. `M1-CSI` is Slim project.

Comment: Then that'a where the error is coming from it's looking for `index.php` in `public_html` rather than in `M1-CSI`, and root ownership is the wrong way. Or note that `apache` runs it's root as `/var/www/html` and so we do `localhost/dir_name` to get at `index.php`

Comment: How can I fix it ? Change .htaccess ? Change project location ?

Comment: When I add die('ok'); at the begenning of `index.php` that's works, 'ok' is writen

Comment: that's was just a Slim error in the code ... I'm sorry !

Comment: Although this answer my work, it is not the best practice to enable ~/public_html. Use https://askubuntu.com/questions/263286/how-to-give-public-html-to-each-user , see the apache module "userdir" , see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP and https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/20/ubuntu-16-04-debian-8-install-apache2-userdir-and-run-web-server-for-each-user/

Comment: @Panther I do believe this is just on OPs computer and not on a VPS or so so using `userdir` isn't as important in this case